# Когда узел синхронизирует свои часы с часами другого узла?

Tags: архитектура

когда узел синхронизирует свои часы с часами другого узла, считается что хорошей идеей является также принять во внимание предыдущие измерения. Почему так? Можете привести пример пожалуйсат?

Comment: Что такое "узел" в вашем понимании?

Comment: Кем считается?.

Comment: @eldgammel Может "использование предыдущих измерений" означает что при синхронизации во первых посылается несколько раз туда-обратно запрос, чтобы расчитать мат-ожидание задержки, дисперсию и другие статистики, чтобы точно вычислить то какую задержку следует прибавить к присланному времени. Также, уверен что статистику прошлого обмена также вполне протоколы могут использовать, например в качестве отправного стартового значения (приближения) статистик текущего обмена.